# How to process various tasks like video acquisition parallel in Matlab?

Tags: camera, matlab

I want to acquire image data from stereo camera simultaneously, or in parallel, save somewhere and read the data when need.

Currently I am doing

```
for i=1:100
start([vid1 vid2]);
imageData1=getdata(vid1,1);
imageData2=getdata(vid2,1);

%do several calculations%
....
end
```

In this cameras are working serially and it is very slow. How can I make 2 cameras work at a time???

Please help..

P.S : I also tried parfor but it does not help .

Regards

Comment: have you tried `parfor`?

Comment: No...can u please explain...what is that????

Comment: it's the same as `for` and used the same way, just it can use parallel compution for independent calculations within a loop. Could be that it has now effect in your certain case, but it's worth a try. (it requires the Parallel Computing Toolbox)

Comment: I am not sure How I can use parfor to get images datas in parallel.

Comment: first type `ver` in your matlab prompt to check whether you have the `Parallel Computing Toolbox` or not. If so, just substitute `for` with `parfor` and see if you get a speed up. Otherwise my comment won't help you.

Comment: yeah my matlab supports parallel computing toolbox

Comment: But it doesn't work for image acquisition I think..getting errors..

Answer (score 1):

**No Parallel Computing Toolbox required!**

The following solution can generally solve problems like yours:

First the videos, I just use some vectors as "data" and save them to the workspace, these would be your two video files:

```
% Creating of some "videos"
fakevideo1 = [1 ; 1 ; 1];
save('fakevideo1','fakevideo1');
fakevideo2 = [2 ; 2 ; 2];
save('fakevideo2','fakevideo2');
```

The basic trick is to create a function which generates another instance of Matlab:

```
function [ ] = parallelinstance( fakevideo_number )

% create command
% -sd (set directory), pwd (current directory), -r (run function) ...
% finally "&" to indicate background computation
command = strcat('matlab -sd',{' '},pwd,{' '},'-r "processvideo(',num2str(fakevideo_number),')" -nodesktop -nosplash &');
% call command
system( command{1} );

end
```

**Most important is the use of `&` at the end of the terminal command!**

Within this function another function is called where the actual video processing is done:

```
function [] = processvideo( fakevideo_number )

% create file and variable name
filename = strcat('fakevideo',num2str(fakevideo_number),'.mat');
varname = strcat('fakevideo',num2str(fakevideo_number));
% load video to workspace or whatever
load(filename);
A = eval(varname);
% do what has to be done
results = A*2;
% save results to workspace, file, grandmothers mailbox, etc.
save([varname 'processed'],'results');
% just to show that both processes run parallel
pause(5)
exit

end
```

Finally call the two processes in your main script:

```
% function call with number of video: parallelinstance(fakevideo_number)
parallelinstance(1);
parallelinstance(2);
```

My code is completely executable, so just play around a bit. I tried to keep it simple.
After all you will find two `.mat` files with the processed video "data" in your workspace.

Be aware to adjust the string `fakevideo` to name root of all your video files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am not sure how to use your answer. I cannot run it directly, it already has some errors.can you please give me some link of such examples.

Comment: what errors? create two function files `parallelinstance` and `processvideo` with the according code and a script file with the the first and the last part of the answer. Run the main script, do you still get errors? which ones?

Comment: Hi, no error, but how do I get the image frames? and where do I specify the cameras video format an all...do I specify it in the fake video part?A am a bit confused, the answer is not very clear to me.thanks

Comment: well I assumed you know how to process your videos, that seemed not to be the question, as I though you already did it once, but it was too slow. I can't help you on that. Just put everything what you would do with a single video in the `processvideo` function. the rest is is just to organize the multiple instances.